# How to update a manually installed software package properly (here: Simplenote)?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, deb

I have installed Simplenote 1.0.0 for Ubuntu by downloading the .deb file and using the command line as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line). As there is no ppa for this app, a notification now explains that I could update to version 1.0.1 manually.

So how to update .deb packages properly without using data and without having installed two versions of the same software in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the deb package for the updated version then do:

```
dpkg -i <package-name>.deb
```

Unless they changed everything around which is very unlikely this should overwrite your previous installation but should leave your settings intact.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure whether the new version would be installed independently from the existing one and thus, I would end up having both versions installed at a time.